# In Xcode, how do I create an outlet for a button that is inside a container?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uicontainerview

I'm a total newbie with xcode and swift, trying to wrap my head around ios programming.

I'm designing a storyboard for my app. The storyboard uses containers to keep track of the controls. In one of the containers resides a button. I want to create an outlet for it to add some code when it is clicked.

If the button would be on the base viewport of the storyboard, I would control-drag a blue line from the button to the source window with my UIViewController subclass file, and it would assist me in generating the code. But for some reason when the button is in a container, this just doesn't work.

When following the documentation, it says to open the assistant editor when the button is selected and it should open the relevant file. So it open an objective-c file, but when I try to control-drag into it, it informs me that I do not have write permissions. Also I feel like I should be doing it in a subclass instead.

I have searched online a lot and tried everything I can think about, but nothing has worked so far. How does this work? Can I do it programmatically or so perhaps? I hope someone can straighten out this question mark...

Comment: Put the button outside the container, control-drag to create an outlet, then move the button inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

A container view is intended to represent an area that will host a view from a different view controller that becomes a child of the view controller that owns the container.  Usually, you would create a second view controller, link your container view to it using an "embed" segue, and then put your buttons and such in the second controller's view.  The code behind those would then go into the second controller.

If your purpose is simply to have superviews to control layout within a single view controller, use a `UIView` rather than a container and the problem goes away.  That's what the Editor->Embed In->View menu item is for.